# How to change font color in Apache POI word document on a specific table cell without using paragraph and run?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a method for formatting a table cell according to some criteria and the problem is that when using paragraph and run it creates a new line inside the cell and this is something I do not want.

```
private void setTab1CellValue(XWPFTable table, int r, int c, String label, BigInteger condition, String value) {
    table.getRow(r).getCell(c).setText(label);
    if (value != null) {
        if (condition != null && condition.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = table.getRow(r).getCell(c + 1).addParagraph();
            XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
            run.setColor("FF0000");
            run.setText(value);
        } else {
            table.getRow(r).getCell(c + 1).setText(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an other way so that I could modify the above code to change the font color of the cell without using paragraph and run (or without getting the newline inside the cell)?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed paragraph with index 0 and it fixed the output as pointed by this answer [XWPF new paragraph in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002718/xwpf-new-paragraph-in-a-table-cell).